# Windows 7 BSOD on boot after windows update

Tags: windows-7, bsod

After Windows updates today, I restarted my desktop (for the first time in a couple weeks), and on boot up ran into a BSOD:

```
STOP: 0x0000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000005, 0xFFFFF8000355AB5A, 0xFFFFF880031CB3A8, 0xFFFFF880031CAC10)
```

I tried system restore, but there was only 1 restore point which was from all the way back in January. I tried it anyway but after 10 minutes of running it said system restore could not be completed.

**Additional info:**

I checked my BIOS and it is detecting my rams. CPU is Intel Sandy Bridge i5-2500k overclocked to 4.3GHz. I reclocked it back to stock speeds (3.3 GHz) in case it was causing the issue (I highly doubt that it is). But the problem persists.

Running Windows 7.
12 GB of RAM at 1333 MHz
OS on 64gb SSD.

What is causing this? How should I fix it?

Also, if it is caused by windows update, is there a way to undo the update with command prompt?

I tried safemode, and the blue screen comes up as well, but I am able to access command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an answer to this question, but ended up reinstalling my computer.

Answer (score 0):

More information on the 0x7E bugcheck:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559239(v=vs.85).aspx

The error is too common to know what the exact cause of error is.  Intel did have a sandy bridge recall, I would check to make sure your system if it is an OEM system such as HP, Acer, or Dell or the motherboard has not been recalled.

Comment: It's a desktop I built from parts I bought.

Comment: It feels more possible if the windows update has caused it. I vaguely remember seeing an nvidia driver in the updates list, and some research has said that this problem is sometimes caused by nvidia drivers. Is there a way to redo the update on cmd

Comment: Will it boot into Safe Mode or VGA Mode?  If so you may be able to uninstall the Nvidia Display Adapter driver and fix the issue.

Comment: Worst case you can boot a Linux Live disk and rename nvlddmkm.sys to nvlddmkm.sys.bak or something else, this will disable the Nvidia display adapter and force the Standard driver to load, which should allow you to uninstall the Nvidia drivers and then download the latest from Nvidia.  I always hide hardware drivers in Windows Update as they seem to burn me more than help me...

Comment: Hmm where is nvlddmkm.sys at? I have access to the command prompt so I can do the mv from there as well.

Comment: Ok I found nvlddmkm.sys and changed it to nvlddmkm.sys.old and restarted, but it didn't work =[

Comment: Try Enable VGA Mode

Comment: If Enable VGA Mode works, you can then try Uninstalling the Nvidia or if you can get to command prompt try running the following command:"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RunDll32.EXE" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\installer.1\NVI2.DLL",UninstallPackage Display.Driver

Answer (score 0):

Try Enable VGA Mode or Safe Mode/Safe Mode with Command Prompt, if these boot try uninstalling the Nvidia display driver using the following command:

[image]

Windows (64-bit)

```
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RunDll32.EXE" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\installer.1\NVI2.DLL",UninstallPackage Display.Driver
```

Windows (32-bit)

```
"C:\Windows\System32\RunDll32.EXE" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2\installer.1\NVI2.DLL",UninstallPackage Display.Driver
```

Comment: Safe Mode doesn't boot. How do I enable VGA only mode?

Comment: It is in the same list of options to get into Safe Mode, it will be in the middle of the menu.

Comment: I don't have VGA only mode, instead there's only a "enable low resolution mode" which doesn't work

Comment: At this point I would backup your data using a Linux distro and then try to do a repair install or a clean install of Windows 7.  To do a repair install, you just say you want to Upgrade to the same version.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll have to try that. Does repair install require me to input a new cd key? I don't have my original cd key with me, and won't be able to get it until school starts again in august.

Comment: Yes, but you have 30 days to activate Windows