# How to get windows 7 cd key from command prompt or linux live disk?

Tags: windows-7, backup, reinstall, product-key

Recently my windows 7 installation broke and refuse to boot ([see here](https://superuser.com/questions/299111/windows-7-bsod-on-boot-after-windows-update/301706#comment-324451)).

I wish to reinstall but only have 1 cd key.

Is there a way to retrieve my current cd key with the use of only command prompt or linux live disk?

Note: I am unable to boot into windows 7 but do have access to a minimal command prompt in recovery menu. (safe mode wont boot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do it from WinRE command line

Connect the non bootable drive to another Windows PC using a usb to hard drive adapter, [install Product Key](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) on the Host PC, run Product key and use File > Select Source.

When the new window opens tick the third radio button, browse to the Windows folder on the non boot drive and hit ok.

[image]

Comment: NB: if you already have an old copy of ProduKey, make sure that it is version 1.35 or later (or get the latest version) because before 1.35, it could only recover the key of the booted OS; 1.35 introduced the option of scanning other Windows installations.

Comment: I am getting product key was not found

Comment: try external registry hive, browse to the Windows\System32\config folder of the attached drive, select "software"

Answer (score 3):

I've had really good success with the Magic Jelly Bean KeyFinder tool with MS-Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit editions), plus other versions of MS-Windows and most MS-Office products too:

Magic Jelly Bean KeyFinder
  http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get the key from a Linux live disk (e.g. a [Ubuntu Live DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
), or any linux system that has access to the computer's drive (booted from usb, dual booted etc) - *this may also be possible from another windows system without third party apps ([example](http://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys))*. Then you can get the licence by:

1. **Get a registry reading/editing tool**. I used `chntpw`, it is currently available in the Fedora and Ubuntu software repositories.
2. **Get the registry data**. You will need the file that contains the registry data from `HKLM\SOFTWARE`, this should be located at `/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE` (text case may vary, could be `/WINDOWS/system32/config/SOFTWARE` etc). If you can read the hard disk this should be accessible
3. **Extract the data**. Run `chntpw` with the path to the registry file - e.g. with the windows partition mounted on `/mnt`:

   ```
   chntpw -e /mnt/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE
   ```

   And get the data from the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId` key - you may be able to use `dpi` command, otherwise you can read the key data directly using `hex Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId`.

If you don't succeed, you could check the hardware to see if it has the key embedded using the answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/637971/how-do-i-get-out-my-embedded-windows-8-key-from-a-linux-environment). Or check for a sticker that came with the computer with the licence key written on.

Also if the Windows is a retail or OEM licence, you may just find a unique ID as the key is for use one time only.

**More info:**

- [`chntpw` site](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) *<sup>probably</sup>*
- [`chntpw` tutorial (for resetting passwords)](https://whatisgon.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/chntpw-tutorial-resetting-windows-passwords-editing-registry-linux/)
- [How to Geek - How to Find Your Lost Windows or Office Product Keys](http://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/). You could also download each tool individually, but might as well grab the CD and the boat load of recovery tools.

Comment: If you edit your answer to include a link to that tool, and the tool has a _Windows 7 Product Key Recovery_ tool, I will vote "up" for this answer.