# Use Windows 8 Pro 64-bit OEM licence in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualbox

My notebook came with Windows 8 Pro. It never booted Windows, I erased it and installed Fedora on it.

I have to use a Windows system now, and I'd like to run the Windows 8 Pro inside Virtualbox on Fedora. Two things come to my mind:

1. Is it legally possible? I'm using the software on the same hardware, but Windows could complain finding *other* hardware because it is installed in VirtualBox.
2. How should I activate the Windows licence, given that I have access to the right installation disk/iso/usb? I heard that since Win8, the key is in the UEFI/BIOS. I know I can read it plain text if needed. Could it fail?

Comment: [As for the latter...](http://superuser.com/questions/637971/how-do-i-get-out-my-embedded-windows-8-key-from-a-linux-environment)

Comment: That works indeed. Can Microsoft complain if I use that?

Comment: Not sure if this is true for Windows 8, but I know earlier versions had different images for OEM & Retail packages and you couldn't use the key for one with a disc made for the other.

Comment: Partial answer: I tried to install an OEM disk in VirtualBox and I activated it via the licence found in the BIOS. It said the activation was succesful.
Only the legal part is left. AFAIK there are two opinions here: yes it's legal because you're using it on the same hardware (which is my opinion) and no it's illegal because virtual hardware counts as different hardware.