# How can I extract the Windows 8 OEM product key when I can't boot to Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, product-key

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with preinstalled Windows 8, upgraded to Windows 8.1 which cannot boot now. I am able to get in recovery screen with an USB installation kit.

In order to get the correct, legal Windows ISO I need to provide my product key. I understand that this is saved and connected to the BIOS/Mainboard/UEFI.

If I access the command prompt from the recovery menu, is there any command which provides me my OEM product key?

Comment: Who do you have to provide the key to to get the ISO? Dell? Why should they expect any user to go to such absurd lengths for the ISO? Wouldn't the unique Service Tag suffice? (Note that anyone can download a generic ISO from MS directly without any key.)

Comment: In order to download the correct ISO from Microsoft they need the serial number:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only

Comment: Download the tool linked to from [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/747579/138343). No key required and it'll create an ISO or even a bootable USB for you direct.

Comment: And what happens when the installer asks for the serial number?

Comment: In my experience so far it doesn't and activates automatically on connecting to the net with the key it detected in the BIOS/UEFI. No harm in trying. If it doesn't work for you you'll be in the same boat and can then revisit this question to see how possibly the key can be extracted using a LiveCD.

Comment: A legitimate install of W8 with a UEFI bios should not need the key since it is baked into the firmware.

Comment: @JulianKnight: Yep, that's my experience as well.

Comment: Neh, it's not under warranty anymore, and you can't actually get any costumer service from Dell after that.

I have found a command like this:
`wmic os get "SerialNumber" | find /v "SerialNumber"`

I will try this from the Command Prompt when I get home. Anyway I will report back.

Comment: use a Linux Live DVD and run this command: http://superuser.com/a/638033/174557

Comment: [Some solutions here](http://www.technize.net/windows-8-product-key-bios/)

Comment: I installed the standard Windows 8.1. It never asked for a product key, looks like it can be read from the BIOS.