# Do Windows 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Single language have same activation keys? And is Single Language lighter than regular?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I wanted to revert from Ubuntu to Windows cuz college n stuff. From what i read, The activation key is stored in the motherboard, it's gonna automatically activate. I only have a 4 GB usb and Windows 8 is 4.1 GB (Seriously?). So... Is Single Language lighter? And will i be able to activate it with my regular key?

Comment: No;  They do not have the same license keys. "will i be able to activate it with my regular key?" of course you won't be able to activate a Single Language key with a Windows 8.1 key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those are not the same. All those special Windows versions (N, Single Langauge) are extra SKUs/Editions and need a special key for each edition. The Single Language edition has the same size like the normal edition. The only difference is that the Single Language edition doesn't allow you to install other language packs to change the UI language.

Read the [OEM key from Linux](https://superuser.com/a/714939/174557) and [use a tool to check which edition](https://github.com/chughes-3/UpdateProductKey/blob/master/UpdateProductKeys/PidChecker.cs) the key belongs to.