# Extracting Windows 10 license keys from machines

Tags: windows-10, license

Throughout the office we have several computers running Windows 10 (a dozen or so) but we have no clear idea which of our licenses are activated on which computer. Is it possible to extract the currently used license key from each computer?

We don't use AD or a KMS or anything like that, each computer is set up solely for the individual working on it. We are aware of which keys we own, but we don't know which are in use and where. We have a mix of OEM, MSDN and "regular" licenses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the Windows license key on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1506522/where-is-the-windows-license-key-on-windows-10)

Comment: @TylerH it does not - That question is focused on extracting the key without being able to enter the windows desktop environment and relies on tools that work under linux.

Comment: I don't see that it relies on that at all. OP just happened to be searching for a physical key value in the hard drive somewhere via Linux in-between Windows installations. As you can see from the accepted answer, they were happy to find a solution that has nothing to do with/doesn't require Linux whatsoever. In fact, *none* of the answers there even *work* on Linux.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use NirSoft's 'ProduKey'. You can download it on [nirsoft.net](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html). This is a freeware utility which allows you not only to see Windows keys, but also various other Microsoft product keys.

This method works for volume licenses, as well as for OEM and other standalone licenses.

*Note that it does not officially support Windows 10, but my experience so far has been successful.*

Comment: Office keys through, I think, 2010, but not later versions (which don't store their keys in the registry in full). For those, you can get the last five digits of the key using ospp.vbs, which is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16  Substitute 15, 14 etc for earlier versions of Office. 2019 and 365 are both under 16. That's for 32-bit Office. For 64-bit, substitute Program Files for Program Files (x86)

Comment: There are several decent articles on the web about ospp, or refer people to the ospp.html file in the same directory as the VBS. It lists lots of other interesting command line parms. BTW, I tried ProduKey in a recently updated Win10 VM with Office 365 and it couldn't find *either* key. So our mileage may vary, as they say. But the nirsoft utility is fast and simple to try; well worth having a go with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for going through this. I adjusted my answer to make it slightly more vague but also more accurate when it comes to these keys.

Comment: For me, both Office 2010 and 2016 do not list the 'ospp.vbs' file you refer to. Perhaps that's why it works for me.

Comment: Odd. I've got both (and scads of others in vms) It's there in all of them. Do you have a case of Nasty IT Admin?  ;-)

Comment: We do have custom installer packages, so probably yes. They tell you to turn off UAC as well, so definitely yes

Comment: This seems to work on my machine, I'll go and try it out on a few other machines and report back :)

Comment: @BramMooij Thanks, this seems to be working on other machines as well!

Answer (score 15):

Enter:

```
wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

into Command Prompt (Admin), then hit enter.

This will show the original Windows 10 product key for each machine.

**NOTE: This only works for OEM licenses.**

Comment: I've tried running this in both powershell and cmd, as regular user and admin, but it returns nothing.

Comment: Use an Admin Command prompt. It returned the Key here.

Comment: @John I have, as I mentioned, but it's not returning anything. All I get is `OA3xOriginalProductKey` followed by three (empty) lines.

Comment: At such a machine, right click on My Computer (PC) and select Properties. You should see on the first GUI screen that it has been Activated and the MSDN Key.  I assume you got a paid subscription for the keys.

Comment: It also does not work for me, but we have licenses activated over a server (KMS). From what I read, this fix only works for OEM licenses.

Comment: This works on my side too.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure this doesn't work if you use a license activated over a server such as a Volume License.

Comment: Make sure you know how you got the keys, who from, and how  you paid for them.   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/information-about-msdn-product-key/b9622868-ea8c-486b-825f-da2e78aba37b

Comment: There are some videos on YouTube which mention that you can 'activate Windows for free'; these videos , in fact, just activate the license over a server and do not give you a hardware-specific license for your machine, these also expire when not renewed by the host of the server.

Comment: This method should work with an OEM license.

Comment: @John that is not the problem, we know which keys we have, we don't know which are used and where.

Comment: @MMM - The command suggested by this answer only applies to OEM keys.  If the command returns nothing it means your not running it on a machine with an OEM key.  In fact, every answer you have received so far, only works for OEM keys.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running windows on a **genuine windows copy** that is connected to the motherboard (an OEM key), you can use this command i windows administrator command prompt:

```batch-file
wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

or in Administrator Powershell

```ps1
$(Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

however, if you entered a product key or have a digital liscence connected to the computer, this won't work. You can get the product key that is on your computer with a VBScript as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255656/vbscript-to-return-windows-product-key) authored by Hackoo. There are many different VBScripts well known to get your product key and most of them are based on the registry since the registry stores your product key formatted in a specific way (semi-encrypted but not really if you will).

Sometimes, the registry values change or get removed so in that case, I would use extra third-party software if that is not a limitation or of concern. My favorite right now is [ProduKey](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html#DownloadLinks)

---

<sub>VBScript by Hackoo below</sub>

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
strValueName = "DigitalProductId"
strComputer = "."
dim iValues()

Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
  strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
oReg.GetBinaryValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,iValues

Dim arrDPID
arrDPID = Array()
For i = 52 to 66
  ReDim Preserve arrDPID( UBound(arrDPID) + 1 )
  arrDPID( UBound(arrDPID) ) = iValues(i)
Next
' <--- Create an array to hold the valid characters for a microsoft Product Key --->
Dim arrChars
arrChars = Array("B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","M","P","Q","R","T","V","W","X","Y","2","3","4","6","7","8","9")

' <--- The clever bit !!! (Decrypt the base24 encoded binary data) --->
For i = 24 To 0 Step -1
  k = 0
  For j = 14 To 0 Step -1
    k = k * 256 Xor arrDPID(j)
    arrDPID(j) = Int(k / 24)
    k = k Mod 24
  Next
  strProductKey = arrChars(k) & strProductKey
  ' <--- add the "-" between the groups of 5 Char --->
  If i Mod 5 = 0 And i <> 0 Then strProductKey = "-" & strProductKey
Next
strFinalKey = strProductKey

' <--- This part of the script displays operating system Information and the license Key --->
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
  strOS   = objOperatingSystem.Caption
  strBuild   = objOperatingSystem.BuildNumber
  strSerial   = objOperatingSystem.SerialNumber
  strRegistered  = objOperatingSystem.RegisteredUser
Next

Set wshShell=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
strPopupMsg = strOS & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Build Number:  " & strBuild & vbNewLine
strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "PID:  " & strSerial & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Registered to:  " & strRegistered & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Your Windows Product Key is:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strFinalKey
strPopupTitle = "Microsoft Windows License Information"
wshShell.Popup strPopupMsg,,strPopupTitle,vbCancelOnly+vbinformation
```

<sub>Another VBScript that works</sub>

```
Option Explicit
Dim objshell,path,DigitalID, Result
Set objshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Set registry key path
Path = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\"
'Registry key value
DigitalID = objshell.RegRead(Path & "DigitalProductId")
Dim ProductName,ProductID,ProductKey,ProductData
'Get ProductName, ProductID, ProductKey
ProductName = "Product Name: " & objshell.RegRead(Path & "ProductName")
ProductID = "Product ID: " & objshell.RegRead(Path & "ProductID")
ProductKey = "Installed Key: " & ConvertToKey(DigitalID)
ProductData = ProductName & vbNewLine & ProductID & vbNewLine & ProductKey
'Show messbox if save to a file
If vbYes = MsgBox(ProductData & vblf & vblf & "Save to a file?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BackUp Windows Key Information") then
Save ProductData
End If
'Convert binary to chars
Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
Dim isWin8, Maps, i, j, Current, KeyOutput, Last, keypart1, insert
'Check if OS is Windows 8
isWin8 = (Key(66) \ 6) And 1
Key(66) = (Key(66) And &HF7) Or ((isWin8 And 2) * 4)
i = 24
Maps = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Current= 0
j = 14
Do
Current = Current* 256
Current = Key(j + KeyOffset) + Current
Key(j + KeyOffset) = (Current \ 24)
Current=Current Mod 24
j = j -1
Loop While j >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Maps,Current+ 1, 1) & KeyOutput
Last = Current
Loop While i >= 0

If (isWin8 = 1) Then
keypart1 = Mid(KeyOutput, 2, Last)
insert = "N"
KeyOutput = Replace(KeyOutput, keypart1, keypart1 & insert, 2, 1, 0)
If Last = 0 Then KeyOutput = insert & KeyOutput
End If
ConvertToKey = Mid(KeyOutput, 1, 5) & "-" & Mid(KeyOutput, 6, 5) & "-" & Mid(KeyOutput, 11, 5) & "-" & Mid(KeyOutput, 16, 5) & "-" & Mid(KeyOutput, 21, 5)
End Function
'Save data to a file
Function Save(Data)
Dim fso, fName, txt,objshell,UserName
Set objshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
'Get current user name
UserName = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserName%")
'Create a text file on desktop
fName = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Desktop\WindowsKeyInfo.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set txt = fso.CreateTextFile(fName)
txt.Writeline Data
txt.Close
End Function
```

Comment: @Hackoo is not the original author of the code, you can read the conversations below. Hackoo also shown a link of the original author, but that's broken

Comment: This answer is a combination of the answers that were already there. May I ask why you posted an answer that doesn't seem to add anything to the answers that were there? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is not intended to be a collection of the current answers but does happen to be so. I have encountered this task before when transferring keys from 1 computer to another one and this is what I did from my limited experience of a student.

Comment: What does "connected to the motherboard" mean?  That's a strange phrase.  Do you mean an OS on bare metal, as opposed to being a VM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this excellent VBScript code found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255656/vbscript-to-return-windows-product-key

> ```
> const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
>
> strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
> strValueName = "DigitalProductId"
> strComputer = "."
> dim iValues()
>
> Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
>   strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
> oReg.GetBinaryValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,iValues
>
> Dim arrDPID
> arrDPID = Array()
> For i = 52 to 66
>   ReDim Preserve arrDPID( UBound(arrDPID) + 1 )
>   arrDPID( UBound(arrDPID) ) = iValues(i)
> Next
> ' <--- Create an array to hold the valid characters for a microsoft Product Key --->
> Dim arrChars
> arrChars = Array("B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","M","P","Q","R","T","V","W","X","Y","2","3","4","6","7","8","9")
>
> ' <--- The clever bit !!! (Decrypt the base24 encoded binary data) --->
> For i = 24 To 0 Step -1
>   k = 0
>   For j = 14 To 0 Step -1
>     k = k * 256 Xor arrDPID(j)
>     arrDPID(j) = Int(k / 24)
>     k = k Mod 24
>   Next
>   strProductKey = arrChars(k) & strProductKey
>   ' <--- add the "-" between the groups of 5 Char --->
>   If i Mod 5 = 0 And i <> 0 Then strProductKey = "-" & strProductKey
> Next
> strFinalKey = strProductKey
>
>
> ' <--- This part of the script displays operating system Information and the license Key --->
> strComputer = "."
> Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
>   & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
> Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
>   ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
> For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
>   strOS   = objOperatingSystem.Caption
>   strBuild   = objOperatingSystem.BuildNumber
>   strSerial   = objOperatingSystem.SerialNumber
>   strRegistered  = objOperatingSystem.RegisteredUser
> Next
>
> Set wshShell=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
> strPopupMsg = strOS & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
> strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Build Number:  " & strBuild & vbNewLine
> strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "PID:  " & strSerial & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
> strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Registered to:  " & strRegistered & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
> strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Your Windows Product Key is:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strFinalKey
> strPopupTitle = "Microsoft Windows License Information"
> wshShell.Popup strPopupMsg,,strPopupTitle,vbCancelOnly+vbinformation
> ```

It will pop up a message including OS version, build number, OEM product ID and the product key from registry. Activation is required before doing this, otherwise it will return wrong product key. To find product key without activation, you can try KeyFinder https://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

Comment: This appears to return a different key than @BramMooij's answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use Belarc Advisor, downloadable from Belarc.com.

It will give you a comprehensive list of the software on the computer, as well as their license keys.

Answer (score -2):

get a copy of RecoverKeys
recover-keys.com
It will also work (if you choose) to scan across network or on a second drive in our machine (example, I moved an old C: drive into my new machine and RK found the serials and prod #'s on that drive too.

Then you can save all keys to a database it keeps