# Is there a more recent mechanism to extract Windows Cdkeys?

Tags: windows, license-key

I was checking possible options like [Nirsoft extractor](https://superuser.com/a/1560968/697749), but I find it's slighly old option, and I'm looking for something that could work for newer Microsoft software versions like Windows 11

Does anyone know a solution to exact such license keys from already installed products?

I've recently purchased a dubious origin laptop with an already OEM Windows license installed, and I would like to do a clean format.

Comment: If it truly is an OEM license, it is embedded in the firmware. If it isn’t, it’s counterfeit.

Comment: [Product Key Scanner For Windows 10/8/7/Vista/XP](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_key_scanner.html) is much newer